# If $q_n$ converges to $b$ ,why is $b$ part of the natural numbers in a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

A question I found while researching reads as follows :

Let $q_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ . Suppose $q_n \to b$ in $\mathbb{R}$

1. I am trying to explain why $b \in\mathbb{N}$.
   Logic tells me that the sequence converges in $\mathbb{N}$ so the limit has to be in $\mathbb{N}$ .

adjoined to that, i need to show that there is  $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q_n= b$ for all $n \ge N$.

Is this not straight from the definition of convergence?

Comment: Well, the same isn’t true for $\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb N.$ So it has to be something specific about $\mathbb N.$

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is an unbouned set so $q_n$ has to be atleast bounded in order to even qualify for being convergent, which is possible if $q_n $ is defined on finitely many $n$'s that is there has to be repetition after some $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence converges to b then b must be a limit point of N and since N is a closed set so N contains its limit points and heance b$\in$N. A closed set are those sets which contains its limit point. And for the second part we need to show that any convergent sequence in N are eventually constant.

Answer (score 0):

Visually the integers in the sequence either become the same or, since they are integers, stay at least $1$ apart from each other. So if they converge to something then it has to be the first case.

Formally if $q_n\to b$ then there is $N$ such that $q_n$ is within $1/3$ (say) of $b$ for all $n\geq N$. So for $m,n\geq N$, $q_m$ and $q_n$ are within $2/3$ of each other by the triangle inequality. So $q_m=q_n$ since they are integers.

So the sequence is eventually constant, and that tells you something about $b$.